Attach and debug NVim current running session's plugin with a lua debugger
I'm developing a plugin that will utilize treesitter and keyboard shorts for nvim dev and woulld like my nvim plugin to trigger a breakpoint after pressing a keyshortcut(defined in init.lua) that executes this lua function.
Is that possible to do that with nvim easily?
I did manage to degub plain lua files in nvim but not NVIm it's self and there's not much actual info about debugging nvim pluggings not even debugging lua so that's why I decided to shift my struggle to here.
Any idea and tips?
